# how to generate auto ID in C#? A0000 to Z9999 and start over with A0000

Tags: c#, automation

```
        private static string ancient;
        public static string MtrclGENERERTOR()
        {
            char[] t = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
            int i;
            for (int j = 0; j < t.Length ; j++)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    sancient = t[j] + i.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
                }
                if(i == 9999)
                {
                        j += 1;
                }
               
            }
            if (sancient == "Z9999")
            {
                sancient = "A0000";
                MtrclGENERERTOR();
            }
            return ancient;
        }
```

*and it shows me one result which is Z9999, *
*it works perfectly without being inside a method, but when I tried to complete my class with the method but it give all the object one value which is "Z9999"*

Comment: a) what are you even trying to do? b) "doesn't work" is ***not*** an error description c) welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Comment: You have a loop where you race through all values (with some jumbled logic) and then return one single final value (if I ignore possible typos)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's easier to count from 10000 to 269999 and use the first digits (divide by 10000) as the index to get the letter

```
for(int x = 10000; x <= 26999; x++)
  Console.WriteLine(t[x/10000] + (x%10000).ToString("0000"));
```